# Inconsistent free space being reported in macOS El Capitan (10.11.6)

Tags: macos

My partner's Mac running macOS El Capitan (10.11.6) says that it has 873GB free out of 1TB, but the blue segment for Apps shows as using 544GB, which is inconsistent with the 873GB free. Is it just out of sync at this moment in time?

[image]

Comment: It's 10.11.6, and sadly there is no Manage button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> “Is it just out of sync at this moment in time?”

Most likely, this is the case.

Since you mention you are using macOS 10.11.6 (El Capitan), this [2015 article from MacWorld](https://www.macworld.com/article/2997252/storage/the-case-of-the-missing-el-capitan-hard-disk-space.html) seems to address the issue. The comparison being made is between Finder-based numbers and numbers reflected when in the Terminal and running `df -h`:

> If these don’t agree, it’s likely a Spotlight error. Apple relies on Spotlight to mark and calculate remaining storage on the startup volume. You can delete the Spotlight index and rebuild it by following these steps:

The steps in included are as follows, but I am providing them mainly for reference purposes; see my tip following:

> 1. Open the Spotlight preference pane.
> 2. Click the Privacy tab.
> 3. Drag the startup volume into the Privacy window.
> 4. Click OK at the warning, and the Spotlight index is deleted.
> 5. Select your startup volume in the privacy list, and click the - (minus) button.

My preferred way of doing this is via the Terminal via these three commands. First, remove the old Spotlight index like this:

```
sudo rm -R /.Spotlight-V100
```

Now, be sure to turn on the [`mdutil`](https://ss64.com/osx/mdutil.html) (metadata utility) with the `-i on` option (“Sets the indexing status for the provided volumes to on or off.”) like this:

```
sudo mdutil -i on /
```

And then run this `mdutil` command with the `-E` option (“This flag will cause each local store for the volumes indicated to be erased. The stores will be rebuilt if appropriate.” to ensure the Spotlight indexes are rebuilt:

```
sudo mdutil -E /
```

Note all of these commands act on the root (`/`) volume but can also be used for other non-`root` volumes. But in this case `/` is fine.